# CentOS with nodeworx

Tags: centos, package-management, libraries, c++

I have a server CentOS 6.9 with interworx and I can't install `libstdc++-static`.
When I do `sudo yum install -y libstdc++-static`

returns with:

> No package libstdc++-static available.

How can I install this package without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Centos 6.9 you need to install `libstdc++-devel` package:

```
$ rpm -qpl libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64.rpm | grep .a$
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.a # (statically linked library)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libsupc++.a # (statically linked library)
```

Comment: With `sudo yum install -y libstdc++-devel` I get `Package libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: You have installed static libraries. Are you sure that problem in `libstdc++-static`?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I was trying to compile some program and got `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"` my gcc version is 4.4.7

Comment: Support of c++11 begins from gcc-4.7. More info in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23523710/4688800. You can redefine build flag during configure step and set `-std=gnu++0x` or install(build) new gcc version instead.

Comment: I getting a lot of deppendies missing trying to build this s@!% -.-' but thx for the time :) I gonna mark as solved.

Comment: Especially for this cases I recommend to you use Docker. Please see in this destination. It may decrease headache during build this application. Hope it's will be helpful for you.